# Problem in Greek letter on R plots using Rqtl package

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am trying to plot a QTL graph with a greek symbole in my legend like this :

> LOD(π,μ)

Here is my code :

```
plot(outFW.2p14a,lodcolumn=1:3, col = c("black","blue","green"),
       ylab="LOD scores for 2014",ylim=c(0,5), main="B")
legend("topright", 
legend=c("LOD(π,μ)", "LOD(π)","LOD(μ)"," ",
"LOD threshold (μ)","LOD threshold (π)","LOD threshold (π,μ)"),
 col=c("black","blue","green","white","red","red","red"),
lty=c(1,1,1,1,2,3), cex=1.2)
```

When I use this code I get the right plot but the legend where the greek symbole π appears is wrong and show a 'p' instead...Just like this : 
[Legend example with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKdfx.png) and for μ it works just fine !

I am using genetic data and tables from Rqtl package but I don't think that the problem comes from there but more from the plot function. Do you have any idea why μ works and not π ?

I would appreciate some help for this because I have tried many things and I can not get it right. I need it for a publication in a scientific journal so it needs to be right.

Best regards,

Diana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the symbol correctly if i use your code..

```
COLS=c("black","blue","green","white","red","red","red")
LABEL1 = c("LOD(π,μ)", "LOD(π)","LOD(μ)"," ",
"LOD threshold (μ)","LOD threshold (π)","LOD threshold (π,μ)")

plot(NULL,ylab="LOD scores for 2014",ylim=c(0,5), main="B",xlim=c(0,5))
legend("topright", 
legend=LABEL1,
 col=COLS,
lty=c(1,1,1,1,2,3), cex=1.2)
```

[image]

Might be something weird with your keyboard, try this, where you call the symbol through expression:

```
LABEL2 = c(expression(paste("LOD(",pi,",",mu,")")),
expression(paste("LOD(",pi,")")),
expression(paste("LOD(",mu,")")),
expression(paste("LOD threshold(",pi,",",mu,,")")),
expression(paste("LOD threshold (",pi,")")),
expression(paste("LOD threshold (",mu,")"))
)

plot(NULL,ylab="LOD scores for 2014",ylim=c(0,5), main="B",xlim=c(0,5))
legend("topright", 
legend=LABEL2,
 col=COLS,
lty=c(1,1,1,1,2,3), cex=1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! Now it works perfectly fine using the expression with LABEL2 ! I guess it was something about my keyboard ...